# Jasmine unit testing - undefined function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm getting error message in terminal `Expected undefined to be greater than 18.` I've created a function and i'm calling the function in expect function. Do I need to pass function as a variable?

```
describe("Age Test", function() {
    it("It calculates age and the return value must be greater than 18", 
    function(){
        /* Define */
        function ageCalculator(yDD,yMM,yYY) {

            // Current date
            var today = new Date();
            var cDD = today.getDate();
            var cMM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
            var cYY = today.getFullYear();

            // Difference in date
            var dDD = cDD - yDD;
            var dMM = cMM - yMM;
            var dYY = cYY - yYY;
            if (dMM < 0) {
                dYY = dYY - 1;
            }

            if (dDD < 0) {
                dMM = dMM - 1;
            }

            dDD = dDD - 1;

            dMM = 12 + dMM;
            dDD = 30 + dDD;

        }

        /* Run Mock */
        expect(ageCalculator(27,4,1991)).toBeGreaterThan(18);
    });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything from the function hence the result of `ageCalculator(27,4,1991)` call is `undefined`.